# Escaping text in Wordpress using built in functions

Tags: php, wordpress, security, wordpress-theming

Not sure to what extent I need to escape in wordpress.
I am building a child theme on my local machine, and want to make sure its secure.

So when ever I echo data contained in a variable I am using this:

```
esc_html_e( $user_info->first_name, 'onepress' );
```

Now if I have a html element like the following:

```
<span class="subscribeText">Subscribe</span>
```

Would I need to escape it like this:

```
<span class="subscribeText"><?php esc_html_e( 'Subscribe', 'onepress' ); ?></span>
```

or would this be going too far.

Cheers

Comment: Yes you can use esc_html_e() to escape text for HTML output